# Group by column and select value if it exist in any columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

For `df` below, how can I group by `Group`, filter rows where **any value in the row** is `Date and Time :`, and select this date value (it may exist in one of the columns randomly). Then assign the value to the entire group as an additional column **before groupby**.

df:

```
    Column0         Column1         Column2         Column3        Group 
17  Date and Time : NaN             NaN             10/01/17,0900  A
18  NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN            A
19  Date and Time : 17/03/17,0800   NaN             NaN            B
18  NaN             NaN             02/06/17,1030   NaN            B
17  Date and Time : 02/06/17,1000   NaN             NaN            C
17  Date and Time : 05/07/17,1330   NaN             NaN            D
19  NaN             01/08/17,1400   Date and Time : NaN            D
    ...
```

Expected output looks something like this(for group A):

```
   Column0          Column1         Column2         Column3        Group     Date
0                                   ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
1                                   ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
2                                   ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
3                                   ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
                                    ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
16                                  ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
17  Date and Time : NaN             NaN             10/01/17,0900  A         10/01/17,0900
18                                  ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
19                                  ...                            A         10/01/17,0900
```

---

Reproducible example:

```
data = [['Date and Time :', 'NaN', 'NaN', '10/01/17,0900', 'A'], 
['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','A'], 
['Date and Time :','17/03/17,0800','NaN','NaN','B'], 
['NaN', 'NaN', '02/06/17,1030','NaN','B'],
['Date and Time :', '02/06/17,1000','NaN','NaN','C'],
['Date and Time :','05/07/17,1330','NaN','NaN','D'],
['NaN', '01/08/17,1400', 'Date and Time :','NaN','D']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Column0', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Group'])
df
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll be grouping by `Group`, and on each group we'll run the `get_group_date` function:

```
def get_group_date(g):
    row = g.loc[g['Column0'] == 'Date and Time :', cols].iloc[0]
    return row[(row != 'NaN').values].values[0]
```

This finds the only row with the right string in Column0, and in that row it finds the only non-NaN column (after we've dropped `Column0` and `Group`).

Group and apply our function:

```
cols = df.columns.drop(['Column0', 'Group'])
grp_dates = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Group').apply(get_group_date)).reset_index()
grp_dates.columns = ['Group', 'Date']
```

We have now determined the right date for each group:

```
In [24]: grp_dates
Out[24]: 
  Group           Date
0     A  10/01/17,0900
1     B  17/03/17,0800
2     C  02/06/17,1000
3     D  05/07/17,1330
```

Now just do an outer join to assign the date to the entire group:

```
In [25]: pd.merge(df, grp_dates, how='outer')
Out[25]: 
           Column0        Column1  ... Group           Date
0  Date and Time :            NaN  ...     A  10/01/17,0900
1              NaN            NaN  ...     A  10/01/17,0900
2  Date and Time :  17/03/17,0800  ...     B  17/03/17,0800
3              NaN            NaN  ...     B  17/03/17,0800
4  Date and Time :  02/06/17,1000  ...     C  02/06/17,1000
5  Date and Time :  05/07/17,1330  ...     D  05/07/17,1330
6              NaN  01/08/17,1400  ...     D  05/07/17,1330

[7 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.melt()` and ignore Date and Time because you can directly look for the only value in that row that is not empty and not "date and Time ...":

```
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=['Group']).dropna(subset=['value'])
df_melted = df_melted[df_melted['value'] != 'Date and Time :']
df['Date'] = df.reset_index().merge(df_melted, on=['Group'], how='left')['value']

           Column0        Column1  ... Group           Date
0  Date and Time :            NaN  ...     A  10/01/17,0900
1              NaN            NaN  ...     A  10/01/17,0900
2  Date and Time :  17/03/17,0800  ...     B  17/03/17,0800
3              NaN            NaN  ...     B  02/06/17,1030
4  Date and Time :  02/06/17,1000  ...     C  17/03/17,0800
5  Date and Time :  05/07/17,1330  ...     D  02/06/17,1030
6              NaN  01/08/17,1400  ...     D  02/06/17,1000
```

---

If it for some reason it actually matters that "Date and Time" is mentioned in that row, you can use this instead:

```
df_melted = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['Group', 'index']).dropna(subset=['value'])
m = df_melted['value'] == 'Date and Time :'
l = df_melted[m]['index'].tolist()
df_melted = df_melted[df_melted['index'].isin(l) & ~m]
df['Date'] = df.reset_index().merge(df_melted, on=['Group'], how='left')['value']
```